# Time Complexity for finding a Linear Decision Boundary

Tags: time-complexity

I am attempting to contemplate how to calculate the time complexity of identifying a linear decision boundary in a 2-dimensional space where there are 2 groups (so 1 boundary). Essentially, given N individuals how many decision boundary lines would I have to draw to test all possible classifications?

I believe the time complexity is N^4. My intuition tells me if I draw a line between every pair of paired points I will test all possible classificaitons. So first I find all possible pairings of points, which amounts to (1/2)(N^2-N), and then employ N Choose 2 to establish all pairings of paired points. Now I draw a line between the two pairs of points.

I thought a proof by contradiction might work, suggesting that the absence of a decision boundary indicates a failure to draw a line between two pairs of points. However, I am currently unsure of the optimal setup for this proof.